# Find a way to extract a float number using condition in C++

Tags: c++

So here’s the code:

```
int main()
{
Int s;
Float b;
Cin >> s;
Switch (s%3)
{
Case 0: b = s + 1; break;
Case 1: b = s/4; break;
Case 2: b = s/5; break;
}
Cout << b;
Return 0;
}
```

I know s is integer and b depends on s, therefore b will be integer as well, which is bad because I want the output to have the decimal behind.

But I can’t change s to float since I can’t check the remainder s%3

I tried if, same problem occurs. So I’m pretty much stuck here.

Is there anyway to get away with this problem?

Comment: Check `s%3` first, then convert to `float` as needed.   Or initialise another variable of type `float` using `s`, check `s%3`, and then use that other variable.     Also, in future, try to post WORKING code - `Int` is not a valid type in C++.

Comment: `s/4` and `s/5` will be integer division.

Comment: Use `static_cast<float>(int);` or `(float)` before a int type.

Comment: Thanks Peter for solution, and thanks for noticing that. I’m just working on my phone and it just turns the first letter Caps. Gotta be careful next time.

Comment: Static sounds interesting, but I haven’t studied till then, thanks anyways Raymond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to to write '(float)' behind every value of b Like this:-

```
int main()
{
    int s;
    float b;
    cin >> s;
    switch (s%3)
    { 
        //Like this
        case 0: b = (float)s + 1; break;
        case 1: b = (float)s/4; break;
        case 2: b = (float)s/5; break;
    }
    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this will help